# What is the vim pattern for guid

Tags: regex, vim, pattern-matching, guid

I am having GUID data in a text file similar to the below one:

`D3C8D467-52DA-4B4F-8821-A589019ADDE2`

I tried below pattern matching in *VIM*. but, they did not work out.

`[0-9A-F]{8}\-[0-9A-F]{4}\-[0-9A-F]{4}\-[0-9A-F]{4}\-[0-9A-F]{12}`

`[0-9A-F]{8}[-][0-9A-F]{4}[-][0-9A-F]{4}[-][0-9A-F]{4}[-][0-9A-F]{12}`

What is the right pattern for finding the GUIDs in *VIM*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not escaping the `{4}` parts but you should, and you are escaping the dash but you shouldn't. To fix this, just do

```
[0-9A-F]\{8}-[0-9A-F]\{4}-[0-9A-F]\{4}-[0-9A-F]\{4}-[0-9A-F]\{12}
```

To make troubleshooting regex problems like this, try setting

```
:set incsearch
```

so you can see the search being matched as you type it. I would also recommend bookmarking [this page](http://vimregex.com), a fantastic resource for troubleshooting vim-regex.

There are also some things you can do for style-readability.

- I would recommend using the `\x` metacharacter instead of a range, sine they are functionally equivalent. This gives:

  ```
  \x\{8}-\x\{4}-\x\{4}-\x\{4}-\x\{12}
  ```
- You don't need to repeat

  ```
  \x\{4}-
  ```

  three times. You can just require three matches:

  ```
  \x\{8}-\(\x\{4}-\)\{3}\x\{12}
  ```
- You can turn on 'magic' which will let you use less backslashes.

  ```
  \v\x{8}-(\x{4}-){3}\x{12}
  ```

That is the shortest and most readable version I am aware of.

Comment: Nice one, didn't know about `\v`!

Answer (score 2):

Vim needs a different kind of escaping:

```
[A-F0-9]\{8}-[A-F0-9]\{4}-[A-F0-9]\{4}-[A-F0-9]\{4}-[A-F0-9]\{12}
```

Check `:help pattern-overview` in vim, the docs are pretty good.